# json.net serialize field datetime as mvc 4 did

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

How can I make json.net serialize datetime field as asp.net mvc 4 did, something like

```
/Date(122818919)/
```

I want to change serializer from MVC to json.net, but keep existing serialization for some properties. Maybe there is existing converter for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really easy to do.  When you new up your serializer pass a settings object to it.

```
        JsonSerializerSettings _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        };

        JsonSerializer _scriptSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_settings);
```

What I done was create a new JsonNetResult and apply it on that...

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    private static JsonSerializerSettings _settings;
    private static JsonSerializer _scriptSerializer;
    static JsonNetResult()
    {
        _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error,
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        };

        _scriptSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_settings);
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");            
        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType) ? "application/json" : this.ContentType;

        if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
        if (this.Data == null)
            return;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            _scriptSerializer.Serialize(sw, this.Data);
            response.Write(sw.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This allows your controller code to become really simple.

```
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
            JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,
        };
    }
```

That would allow you to do it on on all requests.  If you want to change it on one property of one object the following should do the trick.

```
    public class SomeObject
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    }
```